# Furious with vs at

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

> I was furious **at** her.

Vs

> I was furious **with** her.

Also

> I am angry **at** him.

Vs

> I am angry **with** him.

What’s the difference?

Comment: I would use _furious with_ someone (e.g. _her_), and only say _furious at_ events or objects. This has more details on the usage: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43671/angry-with-vs-angry-at-vs-angry-on

Answer (score 2):

There's no real "difference" between using ***with*** or ***at*** in OP's example context - it's just that ***with*** is [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=furious%20at%20me%2Cfurious%20with%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfurious%20at%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfurious%20with%20me%3B%2Cc0)...

[image]

But as you'll see from the chart, ***at*** is gradually gaining traction - particularly with Americans. I think this is because ***at*** is more "specific" in terms of reflecting the nature of the relationship between the verb *(to be angry)* and the object *(him)* (you *direct your anger **at** someone*, for example; no native speaker would ever use ***with*** in that construction).

It may be worth noting that the choice of preposition is often *highly* dependent on the exact "adjective of attitude". You'll often encounter ***angry / mad / furious at** [something / someone]*, but ***pleased / unhappy / delighted at** [whatever]* would be very rare indeed.

I'd also point out that both prepositions are currently about equally common with [*upset **at / with** the outcome*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=upset%20at%20the%20outcome%2Cupset%20with%20the%20outcome&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cupset%20at%20the%20outcome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cupset%20with%20the%20outcome%3B%2Cc0), but it's almost always ***with*** if the "object" is a person ([see *upset **at / with** me*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=upset%20at%20me%2Cupset%20with%20me&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cupset%20at%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cupset%20with%20me%3B%2Cc0)). This may be a factor in some people's choice of preposition for ***furious***, as flagged up by [@Charlie Harding's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/188325/furious-with-vs-at/188338#comment371673_188325) above. But personally I wouldn't think that minor detail is worth committing to memory.

---

In short, although many native speakers still *wouldn't* like ***at***, there's a clear trend showing that this will probably be the idiomatic standard in just a few decades time - so if it seems more natural to you to use ***at*** rather than ***with***, you should feel free to do so. Just ignore any ill-informed pedants who claim it's somehow "ungrammatical".

Note that the above usage shift is far less noticeable in *British* English so far, so if that matters to you, you should be more inclined to stick with ***with*** (at least for the next few decades! :)